# Cannot get data from Orion Context broker installed in a virtual machine

Tags: fiware-orion

EDIT:
Whenever I try to get data from Orion context broker on orion which is installed in virtual machine, I get the following error.
Query I used:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://a.b.c.d:1234/ngsi10/contextEntities/entity_name",
         headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token' : "Sabcdekdnbhhjh",
         'Accept' : "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
       },
       type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: displayAll,
    error: function(){
      console.log("Cannot get data");
    }
}); function displayAll(data){console.log(data);}
```

I get this error:

```
OPTIONS http://a.b.c.d:1234/ngsi10/contextEntities/"entityname" 
index .html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://a.b.c.d:1234/ngsi10/contextEntities/"entityname". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
VM1513:12 Cannot get data
```

I am using "/etc/init.d/contextBroker start" to start contextbroker and 
output of ps ax | grep contextBroker is

```
1950 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost 83.212.238.114 -db orion -corsOrigin __ALL
 2560 ?        Ssl    0:00 contextBroker
 2678 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep contextBroker
```

where as i am passing all the headers and getting token from pep-proxy installed in virtual image or orion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running CB? Please, edit your question post to include the ouput of the following command: `ps ax | grep contextBroker`

Comment: I understand that you run your PEP Proxy at 1234. Is that correct? In addition, which PEP Proxy implementation are you using (Wilma or Steelskin)? Thanks!

Comment: @fgalan yes, I am using pep proxy wilma , not steelskin, but does that make any difference in getting data from orion?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, I am still stuck to this part in my project. Please help.

Comment: To check if the problem is related with Wilma or Orion itself... Could you try to run your AJAX client on the Orion port, please? I mean, temporarly opening the 1026 port in the VM and using "http://a.b.c.d:1026/ngsi10" instead of "http://a.b.c.d:1234/ngsi10" in the URLs.

Comment: I used the same 1026 as port, i mentioned 1234 as example, but the problems remains the same.If i am not including Wilema (just for a try), then also i am not able to get data. I guess the problem is with Orion. Have you seen some similar problem before?I can refer that too.Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to including "X headers" in the request (in particular the `X-Auth-Token` header) causes AJAX starts the preflight CORS protocol. That protocol uses an OPTION method, which is not currently supported at Orion Context Broker (see [the following issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/501)).

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Remove the `X-Auth-Token` header (i.e. to access Orion directly without intermediate PEP)
2. Use a backend to proxy this kind of requests. [This project](https://github.com/nmerinos/ProxyOrionContextBroker) seems promissing (although I haven't tested personally):

> Proxy for the client-Orion Context Broker's server communication for
>   Cross Domain Requests in the FIWARE platform.

**EDIT:** full CORS support including Preflight has been implemented in Orion for all NGSIv2 requests. It is now available in the master branch or in the official docker and soon in the 1.10.0 version (to be released by early December).

Comment: Answer has been edited (see EDIT block) to include new information about CORS support in newer Orion versions